# Unicode character for subscript prime or equivalent?

Tags: unicode

Is there a Unicode character I can use to have x' (read as x prime) as a subscript? For example, Yₓ', except the quote character is too high and could be read as Y'ₓ.

I'm aware Unicode wasn't designed for this kind of notation and I should be using TeX or another system designed for this. However, for email and communicating over a wide variety of channels, a subscript-prime character would be so helpful.

Comment: I think you'll have to say `let y=x'` and then use subscript y

Comment: @Jasen, not a bad idea, would *much* rather have a prime-like character, but if not possible this may work. Unicode doesn't have a subscript y, but it does have a few other subscript letters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts